# In node, how can I ask a function to return only after it has gotten all of the data it needs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a method called createMessage that I pass a request and a response. 
When this method gets called, it currently returns undefined because it is ending before it retrieves all the data. Is there some way I can get it to wait?

```
createMessage: function(request, response) {   
      var totalData = '';
      request.on('data', function(data) {
        totalData += data.toString();
      });
      request.on('end', function() {
        totalData = JSON.parse(totalData);
        totalData.created_at = new Date();
        return totalData;
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: You cannot. You have to use callback functions for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke a callback inside the end function as its asynchronous. This is the nature of node

```
createMessage: function(request, response, callback) {   
      var totalData = '';
      request.on('data', function(data) {
        totalData += data.toString();
      });
      request.on('end', function() {
        totalData = JSON.parse(totalData);
        totalData.created_at = new Date();
        callback(totalData)
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: And as @robrich pointed out the first parameter should be the error by convention.

Answer (score 1):

Taking @meder's answer one step further: you need to do this with a callback, you can't wait ... because JavaScript is single-threaded.

```
createMessage: function(request, response, callback) {   
  var totalData = '';
  request.on('data', function(data) {
    totalData += data.toString();
  });
  request.on('end', function() {
    totalData = JSON.parse(totalData);
    totalData.created_at = new Date();
    callback(null, totalData); // all done
  });
}
```

By convention in Node, the first parameter to the callback is an error, if any.  Because it didn't error, the first parameter in this callback is `null`.